# Seaborn - KDE line plot change colormap

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn, jupyter

I have a seaborn KDE plot but I am struggling to change the colormap. Even if I change the `palatte` it still remains `Set1`, even if `palatte` is changed to `Blues` or a different palatte color. How might I change the line plots to have the colors in colormap `viridis`?
Also the code is in reference to this question and very helpful answer:
[Histogram of 2D arrays and determine array which contains highest and lowest values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72110766/histogram-of-2d-arrays-and-determine-array-which-contains-highest-and-lowest-val/72112960?noredirect=1#comment127417489_72112960)

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd


np.random.seed(1234)
array_2d = np.random.random((5, 20))

sns.kdeplot(data=pd.DataFrame(array_2d.T, columns=range(1, 6)), palette='Set1', multiple='layer')
plt.show()
```

But when I try changing the colormap I keep getting the error:

```
cmap = sns.color_palette("viridis", as_cmap=True)

sns.kdeplot(data=pd.DataFrame(array_2d.T, columns=range(1, 6)),cmap=cmap, multiple='layer')
plt.show()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_216114/3245378387.py in <module>
      1 cmap = sns.color_palette("viridis", as_cmap=True)
      2 
----> 3 sns.kdeplot(data=pd.DataFrame(array_2d.T, columns=range(1, 6)),cmap=cmap, multiple='layer')
      4 plt.show()

AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'cmap'
```

How do I change the line colors to a different color via the `viridis` or another colormap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, using [`set_palette`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_palette.html):

```
sns.set_palette('viridis')
sns.kdeplot(data=pd.DataFrame(array_2d.T, columns=range(1, 6)),  multiple='layer')
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**:

As pointed out by JohanC, simply pass `palette='viridis'` to `kdeplot`.

Or `palette=list(plt.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0, 1, 5)))`.

Comment: Thank you! :) Is there a way to set the colors for each line in the plot? for example, something along the lines of `linspace` and then calling the viridis color palatte?